# What is the meaning of GPS IAP RNP that appears in Notes?

Tags: gnss, iaps

Referring to the RNAV (GPS) RWY 30 approach, what is the meaning of RNP APCH in the notes section? (Highlighted in YELLOW)

Also, what are the separate DA values in parenthesis? (Highlighted with a red oval)

[image: RNAV (GPS) RWY 30]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The AC covering RNP APCH can be found here](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_90-105a.pdf). Under **RNP APCH Operations** it lists:

> **6.3 RNP En Route, RNP Terminal, and RNP APCH Operations:**
>
> 1. The pilot is not required to monitor ground-based NAVAIDs used in position updating unless specified by the Airplane Flight Manual
>    (AFM).
> 2. The pilot must comply with published and assigned altitudes, and airspeeds.
>
> **Note:** Pilots operating aircraft with a barometric vertical navigation
> (baro-VNAV) system must ensure compliance with all altitude
> constraints as published in the procedure by reference to the
> barometric altimeter.

The full qualifications can be found in ***[APPENDIX A. QUALIFICATION CRITERIA FOR REQUIRED NAVIGATION
PERFORMANCE APPROACH (RNP APCH) OPERATIONS](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_90-105a.pdf)*** (not copied for brevity)

The landing minimums in the parentheses are non civilian minimums and generally for use by the military [although the chart reference strictly says](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/editions/cug-complete.pdf) *" All weather minimums in parentheses not applicable to Cilil Pilots. Military pilots refer to appropriate regulations"* so there may be other qualifiers (Im not a military pilot and cant comment beyond this)

[image]

([source](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/editions/cug-complete.pdf))

Comment: That AC was exactly what I was looking for: What is required of the pilot with **RNP APCH** in the notes. Thanks!!!

Comment: I also found the reference to the military minima in the AIM